# 404 on swagger-ui files with Webpack5 and Angular12/Node deployment

Tags: node.js, webpack, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to get swagger-ui implemented to an existing codebase. The idea is to get swagger-ui working with the `someRoutes.js` file.

When running the file locally, everything works as intended. When bundled and deployed, I'm getting 404 errors looking for swagger-ui files even though I can see the files present on the deployment and in my `bundle.js`. The routes and database files work as expected.

[Error image of files missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU7Cw.png)

[Image of proof that files are present in deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHpqS.png)

I have an Angular12 project that has an api outside of the repo (structure below).

```
├── angular.json
├── api (API side)
│   └── src
│       ├── app.js
│       ├── dist
│       │   └── bundle.js
│       ├── node_modules
│       ├── package-lock.json
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── routes
│       │   ├── someRoutes.js
│       └── webpack.config.js
├── src (Angular app)
│   ├── app
│   ├── assets
│   ├── environments
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.ts
(etc)
```

My `app.js` looks like this

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var someRoutes = require('./routes/someRoutes');

var swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
var swaggerJsDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');

var swaggerOptions = {
    swaggerDefinition: {
        info: {
            title: "API Documentation",
            description: "Whatever",
            contact: {
                name: "My Project"
            }
        },
       ...
    }, 
    apis: ["./routes/someRoutes.js"]
};

var swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerOptions);

var app = express();

app.use('/uiapi', someRoutes); //returns "Connected"
app.use('/uiapi/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs));


module.exports = app;
```

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const {
  NODE_ENV = 'production',
} = process.env;

const outputPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

module.exports = {
  entry: './server.js',
  mode: NODE_ENV,
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      outputPath
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui.css',
        './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-bundle.js',
        './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js',
        './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/favicon-16x16.png',
        './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/favicon-32x32.png'
      ]
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    path: outputPath,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./server.js",
    "start-dev": "nodemon ./server.js",
    "build:prod": "webpack p",
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack",
    "run:dev": "NODE_ENV=development DEBUG=* node ./dist/bundle.js",
    "run:prod": "node ./dist/bundle.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.3.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.1",
    "webpack": "^5.67.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  }
}
```

I have tried several different solutions ([here](https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/issues/90) and [here](https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/issues/176)), and referenced the "official" example for swagger-ui usage with webpack ([here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/docs/samples/webpack-getting-started)).

Any suggestions on getting this fixed? Is there a better alternative to webpack?